# JavaScript image compression recursion

Tags: javascript

I have the following function where user can upload an images and then compress them. The problem here is  that when I `console.log(e.target)` inside the `image.onload` function, it displays it continuously in the console, meaning it is in a recursion and it freezes my app and it cannot do anything else.

This compression method I have taken from the following YouTube video and tried to adopt to what I have.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bXf_UdyDzSA&ab_channel=Cod%C3%BACommunity

```
function addImageToForm(e) {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
      let files = e.target.files;
      if (numberOfImages + files.length > 4) {
        alert("You can only upload at most 4 files!");
        return;
      }
      numberOfImages += files.length;

      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        let file = files[i];

        if (file) {
          const reader = new FileReader();

          reader.readAsDataURL(file);

          reader.addEventListener("load", function (e) {  
            console.log(this);

            let imageFile = e.target;

            let divDocument = document.createElement("div");
            let image = document.createElement("img");

            divDocument.setAttribute("class", "id-document");

            image.setAttribute("class", "image-preview");
            image.setAttribute(
              "style",
              "width: inherit; height: inherit; border-radius: 20px;"
            );
            image.setAttribute("src", imageFile.result);

            image.onload = function (e) {
              let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
              let MAX_WIDTH = 200;

              let scaleSize = MAX_WIDTH / e.target.width;
              canvas.width = MAX_WIDTH;
              canvas.height = e.target.height * scaleSize;

              let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
              ctx.drawImage(e.target, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
              console.log(e.target);

              let srcEncoded = ctx.canvas.toDataURL(e.target, "image/jpeg");
              image.setAttribute("src", srcEncoded);
            }
            divDocument.appendChild(image);
            rowOfPhotos.appendChild(divDocument);
          });
          const reference = firebase
            .storage()
            .ref(`${user.displayName}/game_images/` + file.name);
          reference
            .put(file)
            .then((snapshot) => snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL())
            .then((url) => {
              imagesArray.push(url);
            });
        } else {
          image.style.display = null;
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Not logged in");
    }
  });
}
```

Does anybody see where the problem is?

Comment: You call `image.setAttribute()` to reset the "src" property from **inside** the "load" handler. That will trigger another "load" event.

Answer (score 0):

It's because, you change image src in `onload` function

```
image.setAttribute("src", srcEncoded);
```

Every time, image `src` is changed, `onload` function will be called.